# Sending an automatic mail

Tags: python

I am creating the automatic mail system which I have to send the filtered excel values daily

I filtered the excel values using Pandas and stored that in status, while sending mail using python I got some error like this

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Series found
```

Code:

```
samples = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name=0)
status=samples.STATUS == "Need to Update"
msg=EmailMessage()
msg['Subject']='Limit Sample Management System'
msg['From']='abcd@gmail.com'
msg['To']='abcd@gmail.com'
msg.set_content("Kindly Go-Through the below mail",status)
mail=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)


mail.login('abcd@gmail.com','123')

mail.send_message(msg)

mail.close()
```

I need to send that filtered values only

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Also, show us how you create `msg`.

Comment: msg=EmailMessage()
msg['Subject']='Limit Sample Management System'
msg['From']='abcd@gmail.com'
msg['To']='abcd@gmail.com'
msg.set_content("Kindly Go-Through the below mail",status)

Comment: And sorry for that I am really new to this

Comment: Add the additional code in your question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from this line:

```
msg.set_content("Kindly Go-Through the below mail",status)
```

The error tells you that `status` is a `pandas.Series`. `msg.set_content` cannot handle it, you must convert the series into a string.
Try for example with

```
body = ' '.join(map(str, list(status))))
msg.set_content("Kindly Go-Through the below mail",body)
```

`body` is a concatenation of all the values in the series converted to a string (if they are already strings, you may omit the `map` function).